# How to create under the label in Textformfield, not a border, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

> I want to create a Textformfield. But the label shows under the Textformfield, not the border. And Textformfield corner is rounded and the validation error is below the Textformfield.
>
> [image]
> How to achieve in this type UX design in flutter .

Answer (score 0):

Create your own CustomTextField like this: put error text under TextFormField

```
 class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextField({
    super.key,
    this.controller,
    this.errorText,
    this.labelText,
  });

  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? errorText;
  final String? labelText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: labelText != null
                ? Text(
                    labelText!,
                  )
                : null,
            error: errorText != null ? Container() : null,
            isDense: true,
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: errorText != null,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 4,
            ),
            child: Text(
              errorText ?? "",
              //style:errorStyle,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code that you need:

```
TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.amber,
                    filled: true,
                    label: const Text(
                      'Email',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

And for the showing error under textfield, simply use

```
 errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5)),
```

For more info and details about flutter textfields, visit [this article](https://medium.com/@abubakarsaddqiuekhan/text-field-widget-flutter-90c6c7b4be53#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkzNGE1ODE2NDY4Yjk1NzAzOTUzZDE0ZTlmMTVkZjVkMDlhNDAxZTQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.rQuZnlPe47H3z5D_TVYuAaPlwZdied5Q6yOcfX69lXVHehPNPZ7RTc5AqylIGtsq4GW4CW0ZXkYHK7da2UniTBtk1dW9Tbdc1Ufw0N2LRASDG0Q2eeOO_e9HCfuGhljuNYl_IEvWqhHXywfeVQHzG9HOedpW76jTKCKRjCDu1gCpnexnT9SQ8UspBToFiYzSuPvdldq1C229G05tpJUhyOwLdTxtqt1hAT29TpuwJBcer-5g3ffDAUAOrQnOO8oShrKVcJznkO-5H5uzJftUKIKntKj5wqLsRq0PaxtJfbOVblrwXiiviA5R0hNp0EgjDa6Q1Ukiu4Hg0kecT6PCaQ).

**Happy Coding :)**